# pip3 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate

Tags: python, pip, openssl

I installed python3.7 from here https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-6-on-centos/
When trying to use/upgrade/install pip I got the following error:

```
[cloudera@quickstart Python-3.7.6rc1]$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
however the ssl module in Python is not available.
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip
help install")
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem
confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by
SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
available.")) - skipping
```

Version information

```
[cloudera@quickstart Python-3.7.6rc1]$ pip3 --version
pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
[cloudera@quickstart Python-3.7.6rc1]$ whereis pip3
pip3: /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip3.7
[cloudera@quickstart Python-3.7.6rc1]$ whereis pip
pip: /usr/bin/pip2.6 /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.7
[cloudera@quickstart Python-3.7.6rc1]$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.6rc1
[cloudera@quickstart Python-3.7.6rc1]$ whereis openssl
openssl: /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2o/openssl.doxy
/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2o/openssl.spec
/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2o/openssl.pc /usr/bin/openssl /usr/lib64/openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/include/openssl
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
```

I tried several commands suggested here for this error but nothing helped. Can you help me?

UPDATE

```
[cloudera@quickstart Python-3.7.6rc1]$ sudo pip3 install upgrade pip
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting upgrade
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
available.")': /simple/upgrade/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None,
redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
available.")': /simple/upgrade/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None,
redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
available.")': /simple/upgrade/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None,
redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
available.")': /simple/upgrade/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None,
redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
available.")': /simple/upgrade/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/upgrade/: There was a
problem confirming the ssl certificate:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded
with url: /simple/upgrade/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS
URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
upgrade (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for upgrade
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem
confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by
SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
available.")) - skipping
```

Answer (score 7):

**Follow this Steps:**

pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
***PACKAGE_NAME***

Example --> *pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org* ***matplotlib***

**Hope this helps :)**

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing some basic requirements for python. Try installing all of them with
`sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev`

Comment: libssl-dev is the one missing probably

Comment: I tried that but No package all of them Error: Nothing to do. How can I install them?

Comment: @gigives,
You've already installed pip3. In the command `sudo pip3 install --upgrade` you are missing the argument (requirement to install). If you just want to upgrade pip itself, you need to do `pip3 install --upgrade pip` (you could run it with sudo, [but it's not generally a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37104948/2033046) ).

Comment: hello @kenichi, and then I become the same error. Please look at my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

After going through everywhere, I ended up uninstalling python and vs code.
Deleted all the vs code, python, and pip cache files saved under %AppData%.
Reinstalled python and vs code.

Success.

pip is 19.0.3 and I am keeping it this way because I think the problem started when I updated it to 20.3.3.
Once you update to 20.3.3, you're not going to be able to downgrade it because of the SSL error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by starting pip while in the directory where the executable resides.  Permanent fix was to add the required bin & scripts directories to Path.

Don't forget to restart docker and ensure you have connectivity to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

We met the same issue when we installed python3.11. The reason for this error is that the old openssl is used. Here is my solution

- Install openssl1.1.1

  ```
  sudo yum install -y openssl11 openssl11-devel
  ```

  If you met the error `openssl11-devel conflicts with 1:openssl-devel`, one solution is remove the old openssl

  ```
  sudo yum remove openssl-devel.x86_64
  sudo yum autoremove
  sudo yum install -y openssl11 openssl11-devel
  ```
- Then reinstall Python3.11 again

  ```
  ./configure --enable-optimizations
  sudo make altinstall
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the install command by adding the trusted hosts to pip as follows as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943410/pip-ssl-error-on-windows)

`sudo pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -upgrade pip`

I like [this write up](https://jhooq.com/pip-install-connection-error/) on the explanation of the problem and other solutions.

Comment: your syntax is not working at all. mind correcting it ?